# Parse background notifications

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to use [Parse Cloud Jobs](http://www.parse.com) to trigger a download in my app. The documents suggest that I should use `content-available` to send this background push that would not be visible to the user, but to the app.

I tried implementing it as follows:

`Parse.Cloud.job("sendAlert", function(sendAlert) {
  // Set up to modify user data
 Parse.Push.send({
  data: {
    content-available: 1,
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
});`

I also want to schedule it to run every 15 min.

With the expected behavior that it runs every 15 minuites, and sends a background push notification to the app.

However, when I try to deploy it, I get

> Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in main.js:5

and when I try to schedule it, it doesn't show up, most likely due to the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
data: {
    "content-available": 1,
  }
```

It was trying to do some subtraction without the quotes.

Comment: When I use that code, it is schedulable, but I get the error "Failed with: success/error was not called".

Comment: You need to set status.success() when you are done as in this example in the [Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs-writing)

Comment: Thanks - but now a different error! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636693/parse-com-failed-with-referenceerror