# Parse.com Failed with: ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to run the following parse background job in Cloud Code

```
   Parse.Cloud.job("sendAlert", function(sendAlert) {
     Parse.Push.send({
       data: {
       "content-available": 1,
       }
     }, {
     success: function() {
   status.success("Push Worked!!!");
   },
   error: function(error) {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
   }
  });
 });
```

with the intended result of, when it is run, a "transparent" (not seen by users, but seen by the app) push being sent to users.

When I run it, I get the error

> Jobs:
>       sendAlert
>   E2015-02-20T19:17:22.637Z] v17: Ran job sendAlert with:
>     Input: {}
>     Failed with: ReferenceError: status is not defined
>       at Object.Parse.Push.send.error (main.js:12:5)
>       at Parse.js:2:7940
>       at f (Parse.js:2:6852)
>       at Parse.js:2:6344
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:661)
>       at c.extend.reject (Parse.js:2:6297)
>       at Parse.js:2:6956
>       at f (Parse.js:2:6852)
>       at Parse.js:2:7386

in the log. What am I doing wrong? Thanks, and appreciate it - total Parse novice here.

Comment: Could you please properly indent your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for the word `status` in your code, you will see that you haven't declared it anywhere. A variable named `status` can't just come out of nowhere, so that's why you're getting a ReferenceError.

According to the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.html#.job), the second parameter passed into the `Parse.Cloud.job()` callback is a `JobStatus` object with `error` and `success` methods, so it seems that's what you're trying to use:

```
//                       declare it here   ---------v
Parse.Cloud.job("sendAlert", function(sendAlert, status) {
    Parse.Push.send({
        data: {
            "content-available": 1,
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            status.success("Push Worked!!!");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, how do I declare it? I am new to Parse. Thanks, and sorry.

Comment: hmm, perhaps I am misunderstanding the error... now it is failing with the error function: Ran job sendAlert with:
  Input: {}
  Failed with: Uh oh, something went wrong..

Comment: @rocket101 Yes, that means that your `Parse.Push.send()` is failing and that your error callback is being called. I wouldn't know why it is failing, but that's a completely separate matter from the issue in your question. I would suggest making use of the `error` parameter that you have there to get some idea of what went wrong: `status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong." + error);`

Comment: you need to specify some more parameters for the push, such as a query or a channel. Again, check out the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/JavaScript)