# Parse.com Cloud Code Failing

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, push

I am trying to use the following cloud code

`Parse.Cloud.job("sendAlert", function(sendAlert, status) {
    Parse.Push.send({
        data: {
            "content-available": 1,
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            status.success("Push Worked!!!");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
        }
    });
});`

to send a [silent](http://urbanairship.com/resources/dev-blog/2014/12/10/watch-list-ios-8-opt-in-changes) push alert.

It fails and calls the error function. What is the issue?

Comment: The param passed to the error function might provide a clue.

Comment: What is the error that it is showing? You can also check the error logs for more info.

Comment: @Fogmeister The log: E2015-02-20T20:22:29.903Z] v21: Ran job sendAlert with:
  Input: {}
  Failed with: Uh oh, something went wrong.

Comment: Yes. That is your own message. You have put that text in there. Try doing `status.error(error);` instead. That's what the error is there for.

Comment: @Fogmeister New logs - http://pastebin.com/WNkeZj0c. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. Lol. That's a different error. You can't just pass the error object in. You need to get the error message out of the error. I'm on my phone at the mo though so can't. You should be able to find how to get the error message from the docs. Else try `console.log(error);` and check the console logs on parse.

Comment: @Fogmeister Ok... Hope these are the right ones (at last!)E2015-02-20T20:32:05.018Z] v23: Ran job sendAlert with:
  Input: {}
  Failed with: success/error was not called.                                   Thanks, and I apologize for my stupid questions :D

Comment: This won't fix your code. This will tell you what is wrong with your code. This is what you need to do before asking the question on SO. That way we know what is going wrong and how to fix it. :-)

Comment: You need to check in the console logs on the parse website. (Not the error logs). What you've got here is the error that is sent back to your device (or site or whatever your code is running on). Check the logs and there should be a line that outputs to the console.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but either this question or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636693/parse-com-failed-with-referenceerror should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @danh they are different. That one is about why it gives a referenceError, and is answered and sorted out. This is a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to answer my own question, I got the following code to work.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

Parse.Cloud.job("sendAlert", function(sendAlert, status) {
Parse.Push.send({
    where: query, // Set our Installation query
    data: {
        alert: "Broadcast to everyone"
    }
}, {
success: function() {
    status.success("Push Worked!!!");
 },
error: function(error) {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.")
}
});
});
```